# Trigger the enter key on button click

Tags: javascript

I've seen solutions to triggering a button when hitting the enter key, but what I would like to achieve is the opposite. How can I trigger the enter key on button click using JS?

```
const triggerEnterKey = () => {
  ...
}
<button onClick={()=> {triggerEnterKey()}}>Trigger enter key</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dispatchEvent` to dispatch a

```
new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'Enter'})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this.**

```js
var evt = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'keyCode':13, 'which':13}); 
const textTag = document.getElementById("text");                         
                            
window.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.dispatchEvent (evt); 
  textTag.innerHTML = "Enter was presseed";
});
```

```html
<h1>Simulate enter press on click</h1>
<p id="text"></p>
```